# USB drive dead after stopping copying process on Snow Leopard Server

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, osx-snow-leopard, usb-flash-drive

I was copying to a flash drive from our Snow Leopard server when I stopped the copying process half way through. The device then disappeared from the Desktop. So I unplugged it and plugged it right back in. The device just didn't show up.

I unplugged it and plugged it into a Windows XP machine as well as a Windows 7 machine. On both machines, I right clicked "My Computer" and selected "Manage…". On both PC's, the device was located under Removable Storage, but had no size and no drive letter. It shows up in "My Computer", but when I choose "Format…" from the right-click menu (context menu), it says the drive could not be formatted.

Can someone please advise me? The flash drives is about 5 mins old and should have no reason to be dead. I really can't loose this drive (I don't need the data on it, I just need it to work again), any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is saying that the drive can't be formatted even though it's showing up in the Disk Management console, then it's probably a bad drive. The fact that it happened right after a copy operation is most likely a coincidence. New things break sometimes, I'd return it if I were you since it's still going to be under warranty.